# RecyclerView: No Adapter attached; Skipping layout in fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I found two similar questions but none of them worked. I am using fragment and RecyclerViews. The console displays the error

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxk8y.png Adapter

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J2io.png Fragment

```
   @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listkos, null);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        User user = entries.get(position);

        holder.textViewTitle.setText(entries.get(position).getnmkos());
        holder.textViewShortDesc.setText(entries.get(position).getHp());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return entries.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewTitle, textViewShortDesc;
        ImageView imageView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvnm);
            textViewShortDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvhp);

        }
    }
}
```

this fragment

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_beranda, container, false);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
         re = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyle_buka);
        rvLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        re.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManager);
        loadEntries();



        return view;
    }

    private void loadEntries(){
            database.child("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                entries= new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot noteDataSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                  User user=noteDataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                  user.setKey(noteDataSnapshot.getKey());
                  entries.add(user);

                }
                    rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(entries) ;// This is still empty, probably
                    re.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
              }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.w("LogFragment", "loadLog:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                }
            });
         }
}
```

still not working guys
/*It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more detail */

Comment: Its because your data changed method still not called. so it showing log like that.

Comment: Can you please also post your firebase data structure?

Comment: can you also put your RecycleView initialization code?

Answer (score 0):

You must be create a Linear Layout manager. You must be set adapter to the recyclerview.

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
re.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

```
YourAdapter yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(list);
re.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

It means you haven't attached the adapter to your `RecyclerView`. So, you need to initialized your RecyclerView with an empty adapter. Something like this:

```
re = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyle_buka);
rvLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
re.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManager);

// initialize empty adapter
entries= new ArrayList<>();
rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(entries);
re.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
```

Then, whenever you need to reload and refresh the RecyclerView, **you should not doing this**:

```
private void loadEntries(){

   ...

   entries= new ArrayList<>();
   for (DataSnapshot noteDataSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
      User user=noteDataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
      user.setKey(noteDataSnapshot.getKey());
      entries.add(user);

   }

   // DON'T DO THIS!
   rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(entries) ;
   re.setAdapter(rvAdapter);

}
```

because it resetting your adapter with a new Adapter.

What you need is refreshing the list and notifying the adapter for data changes.

First, add the following method to your **Adapter** to reload the list:

```
public void swap(List<User> list) {
   entries.clear();
   entries.addAll(list);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then add it to your `loadEntries()`. Something like this:

```
private void loadEntries() {

   ...

   List<User> newEntries = new ArrayList<>();

   for (DataSnapshot noteDataSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
      User user=noteDataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
      user.setKey(noteDataSnapshot.getKey());
      newEntries.add(user);

   }

   rvAdapter.swap(newEntries);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This happen because you didn't set layout manager to Recyclerview. 
Refer below example.

Initialize recyclerview

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
```

Initialize your adapter class

```
mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList);
```

now set layout manager to recyleview

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: sure where send it?

Comment: @zack waiting for your reply.... what is mail adrress and password? for login screen

Comment: email "namajdb@gmail.com"
pass "qazwsx"

Comment: dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() give me 0 data

Comment: Just remove ".child("Users")" from loadEnties()